# Argparse parse only before positional argument

Tags: python, argparse, argv

How can I have argparse only parse commands that come after a positional argument?

Aka if I have the command `pythonfile.py -d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -d`

How can I have it so that the first `-d` is parsed by argparse, and anything after the positional command is parsed by that command itself (read `pos_cmd_1 -d` as a single argument basically)

So that the argument list would be

- pythonfile.py
- -d dir
- -e test
- pos_cmd_1 -d -s -etc

So anything before the positional command would be optional.  And anything after the positional command would be part of the positional command itself.

Edit:  When trying to run the command with double dashes, it tells me that the arguments that come after aren't recognized.

```
pythonfile.py -d testdir -e test -- command -d -s
```

It says `-d -s` are unrecognized arguments instead of bundling them with the command.

Comment: how about ending the switches with double dash? `pythonfile.py -d dir -e test -- pos_cmd_1 -d` at least it's clear where options stop

Comment: Could you give some context: why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe writing a wrapper for docker-compose that lets me add custom extensibility, and some of the arguments flags overlap with those of the docker command.  So like have `-d` be parsed as my command if it comes before the compose command (up/start/kill/etc) but if it comes after, it would be part of the docker command.  So `python.py -d test up -d` where the second `-d` would be parsed by docker.

Comment: In that case use the `--`, which often appears for "...then pass *these* arguments to whatever *that* calls".

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my edit I mentioned I tried that, but it still seems to be parsing them, except it is parsing them as positional arguments that don't exist.  It isn't ignoring the spaces.  Would my best option be to make that argument `nargs='*'` then just join them together?

Comment: can you post a [mcve] ? because double dashes work

Comment: In my view, the utility should be invoked properly (i.e. according to its documented usage) from a shell. Use quoting or double dash for that prupose. Those are well-known standards that should be obeyed. Example: `pythonfile.py -d dir -e test "pos_cmd_1 -d"`

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, don't just recommend an alternative parser, show how it solves the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj, I agree with you thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this just by slightly changing your command line to

```
pythonfile.py -d dir -e test -- pos_cmd_1 -d
```

by adding `--`, you tell argparse to stop looking for options. So all remaining arguments are set in the positional argument list instead.

An alternative is quoting the rest of arguments:

```
pythonfile.py -d dir -e test "pos_cmd_1 -d"
```

and (because it creates just one positional argument) use argument parser again on the splitted string (not ideal if you want to pass quoted strings in those args)

The advantages of those approaches is that they're natively supported by `argparse`, `getopt` and also that is a standard mechanism that won't surprise the users of your command.

if you want to stick to your approach, maybe you could pre-process argument list to insert the double dash by detecting 2 non-option arguments in a row:

```
args = "-d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -d".split()
oldarg=""
for i,a in enumerate(args):
    if oldarg and oldarg[0]!='-' and a[0]!='-':
        args.insert(i,'--')
        break
    oldarg = a
```

`args` is now: `['-d', 'dir', '-e', 'test', '--', 'pos_cmd_1', '-d']`

Comment: Both of those do work, but is there no option that would allow me to do this without the user having to input the -- themselves?  Is my only option to preparse the string to get everything after the positional command?  There's a set amount of things that the positional command could be so would I just have to put it and everything after it into its own string by comparing every item in the arg list to the possible commands?

Answer (score 1):

With the simple parser:

```
In [2]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: p.add_argument('-d');
In [4]: p.add_argument('-e');
In [5]: p.parse_args('-d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -d'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-d D] [-e E]
ipython3: error: argument -d: expected one argument
```

It tries to parse the last '-d' and hits an error.  `parse_known_args` doesn't help.

With strings other than '-d' and '-e' `parse_known_args` works:

```
In [7]: p.parse_known_args('-d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -s'.split())
Out[7]: (Namespace(d='dir', e='test'), ['pos_cmd_1', '-s'])
```

A positional with a `REMAINDER` nargs appears to work:

```
In [8]: a1 = p.add_argument('rest', nargs='...') # argparse.REMAINDER
In [9]: p.parse_args('-d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -s'.split())
Out[9]: Namespace(d='dir', e='test', rest=['pos_cmd_1', '-s'])
In [10]: p.parse_args('-d dir -e test pos_cmd_1 -d'.split())
Out[10]: Namespace(d='dir', e='test', rest=['pos_cmd_1', '-d'])
```

`REMAINDER` is supposed to work  much like the '--', capturing input for use by another parser or command.

It can have problems if it's expected to catch the whole commandline, as in:

```
In [12]: p.parse_args('-s pos_cmd_1 -d'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-d D] [-e E] ...
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: -s
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs